# npm command in VM

Tags: linux, npm, vagrant, virtual-machine

I have successfully installed the version of nodejs 14.18 in both in my host machine and VM. After some troubleshooting I manage to make javascripting work in my host machine however when I type javascripting in VM, it says command not found.

[ERROR Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n93S5.png)

anyone know why this message is displayed any help would be appreciated

I use vagrant as VM and it is required.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g javascripting` attempts to install the module globally, which requires `sudo` elevation.

If you just want to install the module locally, run `npm install javascripting` without the `-g` parameter